# Actions on Google / DialogFlow: get user data from idToken without conv object

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have a deployed Action that has Google Sign-in Account Linking enabled. This Action uses a cloud function as fullfilment. We extract the user from the DialogFlow call using this method:

```
function userFromRequest(request) {
  return request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user;
}
```

This function returns this user data:

```
   { 
     "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSU...",
     "lastSeen": "2018-11-29T16:58:22Z",
     "locale": "en-US",
     "userId": "ABwpp..."
   }
```

My question is: how can I get the user information such as email, name, etc, **from outside** the DialogFlow app.

All the documentation examples have a `conv` object available:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', async (conv) => {
  const {payload} = conv.user.profile;
  const name = payload ? ` ${payload.given_name}` : '';
}
```

In our case, we want to simply take the `userId` or `idToken` and retrieve the user info. It could be something like this:

```
const dialogflow = require("actions-on-google");    
const app = dialogflow({clientId: '94661...@apps.googleusercontent.com'});

app.getUserData(idToken); //this does not exists, how to have something equivalent?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idToken is just a normal [JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://jwt.io/) that has been signed by one of Google's keys (which rotate very frequently). Although you *should* verify the signature, you don't *need* to.

You can use any JWT library. Since it looks like you're using node.js, you can use something like the [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package to decode it with something like this:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// get the decoded payload ignoring signature, no secretOrPrivateKey needed
const decoded = jwt.decode(token);
```

You **really** should verify the signature, however, so you'll need to get the keys in a format that is useful. The part of the [multivocal library](https://github.com/afirstenberg/multivocal/blob/master/lib/auth.js) that does this uses the JWK version of the keys from Google and converts them into PEM format to verify.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "google-auth-library" to verify the token and get the payload. here is the link to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token)

Comment: it "almost" work, because when I call client.verifyIdToken(...), I got an error. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Token used too late, 1543580174.785 > 1543175402 - but the logged error message contains all the user details, such as email, name, picture, etc. So, in some sense, I have the information I need, but returned inside an error message.

Comment: looks like your token is expired or you have a time zone issue. make sure your token is valid as you should not be getting any exceptions if your token has no issue. I am using the same library and don't get any errors.